# What is the method to overcome following error?

Tags: c

Look at the following code:

```
printf("Enter name and salary of 'Employee 1':\n");
scanf("%49[^\n]%*c,%d", name1,&salary1);
```

And I input the value as:

```
Harry Wilson
12000
```

the next code to echo those values:

```
puts(name1);
printf("%d",salary1);
```

The output was:

```
Harry Wilson
118592
```

The output of `name1` was fine but there was a garbage value inside `salary1`.
Suggest me the way to prevent this error!! I want the similar input to employee2 but when I tried to do the same it was not even able to take input.

Comment: Remove `%*c,` from the format string.

Comment: Code seems to work with the right input: `Harry Wilson\n,12000`. Output: `Harry Wilson\n12000` .

Comment: You could improve the question with a [mre], it makes testing your code and proposing solution code easier.

Comment: Place a space in front of the `%` to filter out a newline left by any (not shown) preceding `scanf()`, as `scanf(" %49[^\n]%d", name1, &salary1);` The `%d` will filter newline automatically, the `%[]` will not.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` reads input and try to match it with the format string passed to `scanf`. It will keep on reading as long as the input can match the format string and stop as soon as something doesn't match.

Let's take a close look at your format string.

```
Format string: %49[^\n]%*c,%d

%49[^\n] means: Keep reading characters until a newline is found or 49 characters has been read

%*c means: Read the next character an discard it

, means: Read a comma

%d means: Read any number of white spaces (incl. zero) followed by an integer
```

Your input is `"Harry Wilson\n12000\n" which means:

```
input is: Harry Wilson\n12000\n

Format %49[^\n] will match the Harry Wilson and then

input is: "\n12000\n"

Format %*c will match the first \n and then 

input is: "12000\n"

Format , will not match and scanf will return leaving 12000\n in the input stream
```

So your problem is the comma. Either remove it from the format string or change your input to include a comma at the correct position. Also notice that `%*c` is unnecessary as `%d` will also read (and discard) the newline before the integer value.

If the "comma" problem is solved a new problem will pop-up. After successful scan of the integer value there will be a `\n` in the input stream. This may interfere with any following `scanf` calls. Consider adding a space as first character of the format string to remove initial white spaces in the input stream.

**Notes:**

Consider using `fgets` together with `sscanf` (or similar parser) instead of `scanf`. It will give you a much better control when parsing user input. As an example: Consider what will happen with your current code if a user inputs a 100 character long name.

For both `sscanf` and `scanf` always check the return value as it tells how many input items that were matched.

Comment: Okay, however Could you please demonstrate the use of `fgets()` and `sscanf` together? The condition can be like you need user's name, his age and height. User may press `enter(\n)` for each input of name age and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the error by giving the input in the right syntax:

```
Harry Wilson
,12000
```

Gets you successful scanning and echo:

```
Harry Wilson
12000
```

This is because the code requires first one "any character" `"%c*"` which has to be a newline (because of the `^\n` in the previous `"%49[^\n]"`) and gets ignored, i.e. not written to any receiving variable. Then it requires a specific `","`.

Doing a check on the return value of `scanf()` will help you to get it right.
As long as the return value is not as expected, the scanning did fail and any further scan attempts meet unexpected input which probably makes them fail.

Alternatively you can change the code to match the input.
Either by tinkering with the scanf formatting.
Or, as recommended in the comments already, by reading error-prone input (i.e. anything a human types in) with `fgets()` and parsing it with non-destructive `sscanf()` attempts. (`scanf()` consumes the input...).

Comment: Yunnosch, can you please demonstrate the use of `fgets()` and `sscanf` together? The condition can be like you need user's name, his age and height.

Comment: `fgets()` into a buffer. Then use `sscanf()` on the buffer like `scanf()` on input. The advantage is that in case of the return value indicating a failure you can either elegantly discard the whole buffer and try again or reattempt to parse the whole buffer with a different syntax expectation. Examples and other questions which deal with the same shold be findable. You are the better one to find those which are most accessable to you.